# Genymotion CPU is incompatible with virtualization technologies

Tags: visual-studio, xamarin, genymotion

I have been working with Visual Studio 2015, xamarin and Genymotion since 2 weeks ago, all worked perfectly but yesterday i get a error trying to start Genymotion Android Emulator. I got this error "CPU is incompatible with virtualization technologies" but i have been using the emulator before.

I searched posibles solutions for example "there is an other emulator running", "configure Hyper-V, Configure VirtualBox", etc. None of this posibles solutions worked for me.

Is this error probably caused by Visual Studio or Xamarin Update?

Comment: It is very unlikely that any Xamarin update caused this error. If anything you should attempt to turn the Hyper V feature off in Windows.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what options you choose when you install visual studio it might choose the windows phone Dev tools which includes it's simulator, which in turn installs hyperv.

A simple VS update shouldn't change these features, but a reinstall or upgrade might - double check that hyperv is actually off and uninstalled

Comment: I tryied to turn off the Hyper-V but i get a diferent error and y uninstall all visual studio devices.